# CiviEvent multiple participant registration does not save all field values to contact

Tags: wordpress, civievent, profile, forms, online-registration

I've come across a weird problem while trying out the CiviEvent participant registration that I would like to share with you and hear your thoughts.

Here is the scenario:

So, I created an event in CiviCRM and turned on the online registration option. Under the **Registration** tab, I enabled '**Register multiple participants**' checkbox leaving the '**same email address?**' checkbox unchecked. Basically, I'm allowing a participant to register one or more participants each having a different email.

I would like to save the first name, last name, and email. I do this by defining a profile and adding it into CiviEvent event registration form. Below is a screenshot of that:

[image: Profile exposing first name, last name, and email]

The profile exposing these fields is called "Event Registration Personal Information" and is defined like this:

[image: Profile definition]

The problem:

When a participant registers himself and/or another participant, the contact is successfully created within CiviCRM. All fields exposed from the profile are filled with the corresponding data **except** for the email address. Within each contact, the email address field is therefore empty. I tried switching the email type from "Billing" to "Primary", but sadly still received the same result.

Since I use WordPress, I wanted to test the profile and see if that's the problem by adding it as a standalone form using the CiviCRM WordPress shortcode. Upon submitting the form, the contact has been created successfully and all data is saved including the email. This means that the problem does not come from the profile itself, but from the CiviEvent module.

This leads to my question: Am I using the CiviEvent module incorrectly or did I miss some option? Did any of you encounter the same issue?

I am using CiviCRM version 4.7.31

**Edit:**
For some reason, when disabling the '**Register multiple participants**', the problem still persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the solution to my problem. I'll post this here in case someone ever stumbles on the same problem.

When configuring the profile that you would like to use for the event registration form, be sure to **not** set the e-mail type (category) to "Billing". If set, the email will not be saved to the contact (no idea why).

All other e-mail categories seem to work fine (e.g. "Primary" or in my case "Main").